# Run the program or a script when Ubuntu boots without user login?

Tags: scripts, upstart, system

Hello I am a user does not have much experience using Ubuntu and my english is not really good, so I will describe the contents to give you a way easy understand

Purpose: When Ubuntu boots, some software will automatically run without the user login.

The program I want to run is Firefox and some other programs.

I searched for many day and find the instructions to do this. eg edit / etc / init or /etc/rc.local
but all this does not work with me, I think it's because I did not do right.

Anyone who can help me this matter, please guide me in detail and easily understandable for a normal user ( in Graphical user interface - **GUI** ), I would appreciate someone who can give a little time to guide by photos or videos

Another example: what I want to do like TeamViewer program on Ubuntu, they support users by function "Teamview startup with the system" (without the log by user)

I use a virtual private server to run the software and often restart it every 8 hours, I felt very tired when every private virtual server reboot and I have to login to the virtual server privacy to launch Firefox and related programs. I was looking for a solution to perform this task automatically.

I use Ubuntu 14.0

Comment: Do you mean that firefox should run with no user logged in? Or do you just want it to start automatically when *you* log in?

Comment: What Desktop Environment do you use? I would use Gnome if you wish to autostart applications.

Comment: @terdon Yes, exactly what you're thinking ! I want Firefox run when Ubuntu start with no user logged in !

Comment: That's not possible. Why do you want no user logged in? Why not have a default guest user who logs in automatically? You need a user in order to run anything (with very few exceptions), even if it is the root user. Would it be OK to have a user logged in automatically and firefox launched with no interaction from you? That means you just start the virtual server and everything comes up as you want it.

Comment: Right, Firefox has been programmed to work as soon as firefox is started, and some software like i say also operate similarly. Everything was arranged simply restart Firefox, it will automatically work without user intervention, as you say "just start the virtual server and everything comes up as you want it"

Do you have any idea to do this ?

Comment: It's like the way that TeamViewer or xrdp activity, automatically launch when Ubuntu boots without user login. TeamViewer or xrdp ready for operation even when there is no user logged on. it's like an essential part of the system that will launch with the system.

Comment: Explain what you mean " without user login ". When you turn on computer, usually you get to login screen. That's where you put username and password. Then you can use all the apps. So, you don't want to do that ? you want computer just turn on and open desktop, then start firefox ?

Comment: It is exactly what i am saying. Just power up the computer and  Firefox start automatically, not need to do any further action. Simply turn on the power !